# Web part to preview PowerPoint slides

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-search

I am trying to modify the current search results web part / create a new web part that alter the PowerPoint preview panel so that it displays only slides containing the results. Currently the PowerPoint previews shows files containing the results, but the preview always starts from slide 1, and the preview scans through every slide. However, i have no idea where to start researching on doing this. Are there any sites that teach or show the basics of how to make this work? I'm lost in finding help from google now..

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using content search web part.

There are such questions :

1) Are you storing PPT files in  any library ?

2) Is library contain specific content type to store metadata of document?

3) Is there any custom  page layout with  content type which you have included in share point library ?

I assume that u have configured all the things:

Steps:

1)  Create content type name "ctPPT".

2)  Create new page layout name "PPTsample.aspx".  Set content type to page layout name"ctPPT".

3)  Add content type to share point library where you want to store the PPT document. Let's take a pages library.Set custom  content type on visible new buttona and default.

Note : Page-layout and library has to be same content type.

4) open search result web part in edit mode. Click on query button.

```
path:"https://Test.sharepoint.com/sites/Test1/resorces/KnowledgeBase"  ContentTypeId:0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D000C998F47A6DA4381AE73C2926808DF57* (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") {SearchBoxQuery}
```

this query returns only those documents which is created from the "ctPPT" from whole the sub site.

You have to create custom **item displaytemplate** and **control displaytemplate** to display the data in to different way.

:)